# postmaster dead but pid file exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, postgresql, capistrano

We have a rails 4 application with postgres

Sometimes our server hanged and if we reboot it .

The server gets started but it can not connect to postgres.

status shows `postmaster dead but pid file exists`

log shows

```
FATAL:  lock file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 4696) using socket file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
```

and the postgresql could not restarted.

--- After deleting the /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 file and restarting the postgres service the service restarted but the postgres can not connect with host we added.

What can we do to fix this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have another instance of PostgreSQL starting up automatically on the machine. Rather than deleting the socket file, identify the instance that's autostarted and disable it. How depends on what operating system you are using and how you installed PostgreSQL. You shouldn't *need* to reboot a server and it shouldn't "hang" in the first place, so you should also look at those underlying issues; they may indicate hardware problems that could get worse over time.

Comment: Posted very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/31547206/398670