# host can not recognized in postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We have seen a issue in log

```
FATAL:  lock file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 4696) using socket file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
```

We have deleted /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock

We restarted the postgres service the service restarted

But the `psql -h localhost -d database -U newuser`

shows error role 'newuser' does not exists

but if we connect without host

```
psql -d database -U newuser
```

It worked, How can We work with host options ?

Is there we ,missing somthing after deleting tmp file?

Comment: well, restart machine and try.

Comment: Note this user's very similar post http://stackoverflow.com/q/31546303/398670

Answer (score 0):

Same as the last one, you have two instances of PostgreSQL running on the machine.

You delete the socket file rather than shutting down the instance. This allows your second instance to start, but it's only listening on the unix socket. Presumably `listen_addresses` is unset/empty so it doesn't attempt to bind to a TCP/IP socket, since it'd fail if it tried and port 5432 was already in use.

The other instance is still running and still listening on port 5432 for TCP/IP connections. When you specify `-h localhost` you get a TCP/IP connection instead of the default unix socket connection, so you are connecting to the other instance of PostgreSQL on your system.

All your problems are caused by going around deleting and killing things rather than identifying the underlying problem - the second PostgreSQL instance - and addressing that.

Comment: I found 
listen_addresses = '127.0.0.200, localhost' # what IP address(es) to listen on;

Comment: Sure, but you have two instances of PostgreSQL running.  Figure out what's starting the other instance and disable it. How to do that depends on the OS you are using and how you installed PostgreSQL. If you're on Ubuntu for example, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Comment: Yes we found psql (8.4.20, server 9.4.4) our data is in 8.4 . How to disable 9.4?

Comment: @Debadatt **How to do that depends on the OS you are using and how you installed PostgreSQL**. So....